Create utility script for accessing Drive files?
I have a Colab project with multiple notebooks that need to access data files stored in Drive.
At the top of every notebook I currently have this:
drive.mount('/content/drive')
dirpath = '/content/drive/My Drive/nhstech-shared/csv/'
dirpath = input("Enter the directory path or Enter to accept (default: {}): ".format(dirpath)) or dirpath

I would like to move this into a utility file, so I don't need to repeat the same code at the top of every notebook. (I also have repeated code for listing files, creating filepaths etc.)
I have created a utils.py file and saved it in the same directory as the notebooks.
However, if I do import utils at the top of the notebook, I just get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'.
Do I really need to repeat this code at the top of every single notebook, just to access files from Drive?
